# StaggeredGridLayoutManager changing item size on scroll

Tags: android

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to solve this problem.

**1. Bug Description**

image link：https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixvdB.jpg

"left"：Run the apk

"Right"：When I swipe down, the size of the items is changing.

**2. Code**

- MainActivity.java

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
      List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<>();

      memberList.add(new Member(1, R.drawable.baishatunbeach1, "白沙屯海灘1"));
      //add Members

      recyclerView.setAdapter(new MemberAdapter(this, memberList));
  }

  private class MemberAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdapter.ViewHolder> {
      private Context context;
      private List<Member> memberList;

      MemberAdapter(Context context, List<Member> memberList) {
          this.context = context;
          this.memberList = memberList;
      }

      @Override
      public MemberAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_cardview_item, parent, false);
          return new ViewHolder(view);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(MemberAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
          final Member member = memberList.get(position);
          holder.imageId.setImageResource(member.getImage());
          holder.textId.setText(String.valueOf(member.getId()));
          holder.textName.setText(member.getName());
          holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
                  imageView.setImageResource(member.getImage());
                  Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                  toast.setView(imageView);
                  toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                  toast.show();
              }
          });
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return memberList.size();
      }

      class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
          ImageView imageId;
          TextView textId, textName;
          ViewHolder(View itemView) {
              super(itemView);
              imageId = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageId);
              textId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textId);
              textName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- activity_main.xml

  ```
  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Hello World!"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- recyclerview_cardview_item.xml

  ```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
  android:id="@+id/cardview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_margin="6dp"
  android:padding="6dp"
  app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffdddddd"
  app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
  app:cardElevation="6dp">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageId"
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="160dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textId"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
              android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textName"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
              android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  ```

Comment: change this `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to this `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in LinearLayout

Comment: It's not work. When I swipe down, the size of the items still change.

Comment: change height of card view to wrap_content as well

Comment: Thank Pavneet_Singh for your help. It's work.

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the height of `cardview` and `linearlayout` to `wrap_content`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="6dp"
android:padding="6dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffdddddd"
app:cardCornerRadius="28dp"
app:cardElevation="6dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```